# how to replace an primeNg tree icon for a branch node to + or -?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

angular CLI version 6

```
"primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
"primeng": "6.0.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
```

I am trying to change the default icon for tree node to + and -.
I see suggested solutions here but I think they must for older version of the library since it does not work.

Any guidance on this?

[image]

Comment: The expandedIcon and collapsedIcon works to replace default folder icon not the outer caret icon. did you try overriding styleClass? this is the span which decides icon, if some how you can add custom class here or override values of css in present class then you will be able to change icon `<div class="ui-treenode-content ui-treenode-selectable" draggable="false"><span class="ui-tree-toggler pi pi-fw pi-caret-right"></span>`. you can also check styling section for this component on primeng.

Answer (score 1):

From CSS you could replace the Icon content, to desired icon content.

To do this you have to observe the current css classes that are applied to your `p-tree` when you expand and close.

For Example:

The CSS class for Tree Toggler on `p-tree` is: `.ui-treetable-toggler`
And the icon class normal position is: `fa-caret-right` and the content class is: `fa-caret-right:before`

So to replace that with `+` you will have to use following CSS:

```
.your-tree-table-class .ui-treetable-toggler.fa-caret-right:before{
  content: "\f067";
}
```

Notice that I have used my own CSS class as `your-tree-class` so that it affects only the specific `p-tree`. Not all of them.

And to replace with `-` when you expand use:

```
.your-tree-table-class .ui-treetable-toggler.fa-caret-down:before{
  content: "\f068";
}
```

Here is the list of Font Awesome Icons and their CSS content values:
http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Comment: your recommended content value result in a square, i.e. not found.

Comment: Well that was just an example. Find the appropriate one from the link i provided...or may it is different for your fontawsome version.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the icon with this method, you have to set the font-family property too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).